# Poll type question - Should it be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, polling

I've noticed this question; [If you had the power to remove one thing in your daily job, what would it be?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/10087/19799) floating around on the 'active' page and I can't help but wonder how this is still open when questions such as [What stressors do programmers encounter on the job, and how do you deal with them?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/74913/19799)  have been closed.

Did this one slip through the net or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that was an old question that did, indeed, slip through the cracks. I have closed it as "not constructive", as is our usual policy with questions like that.